# Calling command line from C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, command-line, vlc

I want to execute command line from a C++ function. To be precise, i am trying to execute a vlc command in C++. The change directory command works well and the C++ code for that is

```
system("cd G:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC");
```

From this i want to execute the following command in C++

```
vlc -vvv udp://@localhost:1234:network-caching=50
```

I tried the below command to get an error "vlc is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

```
system("vlc -vvv udp://@localhost:1234:network-caching=50");
```

How to make this work? Any ideas?
I am running the system on Windows xp.

Comment: system("G:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc -vvv udp://@localhost:1234:network-caching=50");

Comment: You don't mention what operating system you are on. Read about the "PATH" environment variable and how it is used to locate a program when it's evaluating a command line

Comment: The problems is that when you invoke system() it starts its own shell. Any change in the environment (like current directory) is local to that shell. So the first system() call that changes directory does not affect the environment of the second system() call.

Comment: But using '&&' in the same system() also doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: This is Windows. Use [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) or [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153.aspx) (if you know what you're doing). To correct your question: You do **not** want to execute a command line (whatever that is supposed to mean). You want to start a process.

Comment: You know how to use the command line from C++; now you're combining three different problems: 1) running a program that is not in your PATH, 2) changing directory first, and 3) handling a path containing a space. You should try to tackle these one at a time, before combining them.

Comment: I believe system( "\"G:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc\" -vvv udp://@localhost:1234:network-caching=50"); should work